# incompatible types int[] int

Tags: java, arrays, int

I've been searching for a solution to make the integer sum of two string, and create another string. Now I am working with an array, but I get the following error:

- int[] cArray = b;
                         ^
  required: int[]
  found:    int

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, anybody that can help?

```
public class Woord {
final String JAVA = "java";

public void woord() {
    System.out.println("Geef een woord in");
    String woord = Input.readString();

    for (int i = 0; i < woord.length(); i++) {
        int b = (int) woord.charAt(i);
        int[] cArray = b;
        int c = (int) JAVA.charAt(i);
        int[] bArray = JAVA.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(cArray);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Woord woord = new Woord();
    woord.woord();
}}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error in? are you getting integer value of 1 or 2 strings?

Comment: Well, you declare `b` as an int and then assign it to `cArray`, an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is an `int`, but `cArray` is an `int[]`. You can't assign an `int` to an `int[]`. Try to change this line

```
int[] cArray = b;
```

to this

```
int[] cArray = new int[] { b };
```